# Angular 4 - Value not persisting outside of subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code in a Angular service:

```
 this.signInService.signIn(this.model).subscribe(user => {this.user = user,console.log(this.user.Username)});   
 console.log(this.user.Username);
```

I have two `console.log` statements. The one within the `subscribe` function prints the correct value. The second `console.log` prints undefined, however.

Comment: because it's async. the second `console.log` will be called before any response is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the `Async` system of the `subscribe`. So the code dont stop for the `subscribe` method to retun data. It retuns when is has data. You would probably notice that console has `Undefined` printed before the actual data.

https://www.javascripttuts.com/introduction-to-angular-2-observables/

Comment: I see. I am storing the data into `localStorage` right below. Does that mean I am potentially storing undefined data?

Comment: At thst point yes. when the `subscribe` method retuens value no. That would normaly be like second delay.

Comment: So the simple thing to do would be put the store statements within subscribe right?

Comment: Yes. If you need to run a method on that response data, you would need to put that also in the `subscribe` method. Unless its HTML which will update itself when the data receives.